# How to "render" ouput from a command playing with tput so only the final terminal-postprocessed result is kept?

Tags: zsh, stdout, escape-characters, tee, tput

I captured the output of a script that uses tput to draw certain things on screen. When I perform cat myoutput then everything is well seen (looks like terminal reinterprets it from beginning), but when I edit or pipe that output I see plenty of ansi sequences and all the stuff previous to destructive printing like tput clear and the like.

How can I a postprocess it so I only get the final "render"?

Even better, the origin of this is that I am currently teeing my script so it prints everything to a file aside from to the terminal

with `exec > >(tee /dev/tty)`

is there a way to tell the stdout channel to "render" everything before saving?

Comment: Not an answer to this question, but [```col```](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/col.1.html) does that for Backspace, Carriage Return and Reverse Linefeed.  I guess this is for some ancient printer — maybe the KSR-37?

Comment: col or colcrt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a program that *understands* these terminal control sequences, and is able to render the final view. Well, such a program is called a *terminal emulator*. Some of them are graphical – like the program you launch to use your shell, e.g., gnome-terminal or alacritty, others are primarily headless.

The older `screen` or the more modern `tmux` are the relevant ones here.

1. write an "outer" script:

   1. create a named pipe
   2. Start your "inner" script (so the one that outputs stuff) in `tmux`, in the background
   3. in your outer script, read from the fifo (this blocks because nothing has been written),
   4. once that read finishes, instruct `tmux` to output a screenshot
2. in your inner script, write something to the named pipe to signal you're at a state to be taken a screenshot of

Putting it together, something like

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
# outer script
# SPDX-License-Identifier: WTFPL

# Make a temporary directory
tmpdir="$(mktemp -d)"

# Prepare the FIFO
fifo="${tmpdir}/fifo"
mkfifo "${fifo}"

# Start the inner script in tmux
tmux new-session -d -s "${tmpdir}" -e "FIFO=${fifo}" ./inner-script.sh …
#^   ^           ^  ^------+-----^ ^------+--------^ ^                 ^
#|   |           |         |              |          |                 |
#\------run tmux, the terminal emulator
#    |           |         |              |          |                 |
#    \---in tmux, run the "new-session" command to, well, get a new session
#                |         |              |          |                 |
#                \---detach that session, i.e. *don't* connect it to the current terminal
#                          |              |          |                 |
#                          \--specify the session name. Conveniently, we abuse the name
#                             of our temporary directory, as it's inherently unique
#                                         |          |                 |
#                                         \-- for the started command, set the environment
#                                             variable FIFO to the name of our FIFO
#                                                    |                 |
#                                                    \-- launch your script
#                                                …with its arguments--/

# Wait for something to be written to our FIFO
cat "${fifo}" > /dev/null

# instruct tmux to take a "pane shot"
tmux capture-pane -t "${tmpdir}" -p > "/path/to/capture"
#                 ^------+-----^  ^ ^---------+--------^
#                        |        |           |
#                        \-------------------------------- target (session name as above)
#                                 |           |
#                                 \----------------------- print to stdout
#                                             |
#                                             \----------- redirect stdout to file

# Finally, clean up session and temporary directory
tmux kill-session -t "${tmpdir}"
rm -rf "${tmpdir}"
```

You only need to add the writing of something to the fifo to your `inner-script.sh`, e.g., `echo done > "${FIFO}"; sleep 100`.

If you already have a "recorded" output, your `inner-script.sh` might simply be `cat recording.txt; echo done > "${FIFO}"; sleep 100`

Comment: Absolutely amazing answer. I did a simplified test and works perectly. Ill wait before approving just in case somebody comes up with a simpler creative solutio/shortcut, but I plan to eventually check your answer. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: Played a bit with you answer, ended up adjusting it to my case, it works. And now looking for ways to optimize it https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/772947/redirecting-stdout-of-a-script-as-the-stdin-of-another-script-command-running-in