# What is the difference of passing an sleep command to tmux new-session -d and not passing anything?

Tags: tmux

I was playing with an script that sends text to a tmux stdin after this answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/773049/189571 by @Kamil Maciorowski) and I was wrongly doing this

```
tty=$(tmux new-session -d -s aux -PF "#{pane_tty}")
echo -n foo > $tty && tput cr > $tty && echo bar > $tty
tmux capture-pane -t aux -p -S0 -E3
```

which results in `foo PROMPT %> bar` (undeterministically sequenced, and PROMPT is printed)

whereas the same but using command `tail -f /dev/null` as an argument of tmux new-session, as Kamil suggested, gives `bar` as result , which is what I expected

I would like to understand why without tail everything fails.
Isn't `tail -f /dev/null` here sort of an `sleep infinity`?
What's the difference with not passing any command?
I mean if you don't pass anything to new-session, the pane is kept alive until kill-session as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tmux new-session` with a command starts the command in a new tmux pane in a new tmux window in a new tmux session.

`tmux new-session` without any command starts an interactive shell instead.

In your case `PROMPT %>` is the prompt this shell prints. I guess your line with `echo`s gets executed immediately, so there is a race condition and the prompt may get to the tty (in the pane) before `foo` or after `bar`, or between `foo` and `bar`.

`tput cr > $$tty` did not print to the desired tty because `$$` expanded to the PID of the shell parsing the line. Most likely you have created a regular file named `12345tty` or so, the output of `tput` is inside the file.

Comment: sorry, the $$tty part was a typo. But I see what you mean thanks!!!